# How to add a prerequisite check for .NET framework 4.5.2 in InstallShield Basic MSI project

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2015

I'm going to install a .NET application through InstallShield. The .NET application targets .NET Framework v4.5.2. So I do not want the installation to proceed if .NET framework v4.5.2 is not found on the computer. I want to detect this dependency as part of prerequisite check-up in the very beginning of the installation. How can I achieve this in InstallShield 2015?

**UPDATE**: When I tried going via [the distributables route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821073/465053) as suggested by Shahzad, I faced below error:

> Your project contains InstallShield prerequisites. A **setup.exe** setup
> launcher is *required*.

The project I'm working upon is a Basic MSI project. I figured out that the project should create a **setup.exe** file in the build output to resolve this error. But I'm not seeing any **setup.exe** tab as suggested here in the [official documentation](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/ReleaseGridSetupTab.htm#Ref-Views_109372022_1091686). Where can I see it? May be under **Project Assistant** tab or **Installation Designer** tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm elaborating custom software condition methodology so that it can be helpful for someone if they face any difficulty in doing so. Custom software condition can suffice the need when you just want to check the presence or absence of a registry key.

In my specific scenario, In addition to check the presence or absence of a registry key I also had to compare the value of the specific registry key against a predefined value (379893). I achieved it in two step process:

1. Got to **Project Assistant** tab. Click **Installation Requirements** link at the bottom.
2. Now under **More Options** section in left pane, click <kbd>Create a custom software condition</kbd> link.

   [image]
3. Click <kbd>Next</kbd> on **Welcome to the System Search Wizard** screen

   [image]
4. Select **Registry Entry** on **System Search Wizard** screen

   [image]
5. Select the registry key path where the version of currently installed .NET Framework is stored. In the **Registry Value: (Optional)** field type a variable name which will store the value of the key. This variable is used later on while creating a comparison condition to check for exact value of .NET Framework version. This variable gets appended into the list of a property called **SecureCustomProperties**.  You can see this property in **Property Manager** under **Behavior and Logic** on **Installation Designer** tab

   [image]
6. Put the error message which should popup in case the desired .NET Framework version is *not* installed:

   [image]
7. Install condition thus formed will now be shown in the list with its checkbox checked on the **Project Assistant** tab.

   [image]
8. Now go to **Installation Designer** [Tab] -> **Behavior and Logic** -> **System Search**. Here you will see a new record which correspond to the software search condition we have created so far. Right click on the row and then click **Modify...**

   [image]
9. Do not change anything on first two screens of the wizard. On the third screen having title **What do you want to do with the value?**, select the <kbd>Store the value in the property and use the property in an Install Condition</kbd> radio button. Now click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

   [image]
10. Now a new **Condition Builder** window pops up. Double click **Condition** column to change it. Change the condition to - DOTNETFRAMEWORKRELEASEVERSIONVALUE >= "#379893"

[image]

That's it. You're done. Also, if you want you can tweak the condition in point# 10 based on the .NET Framework your application requires to run. More details about condition is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx) link.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the version of .Net framework in the installation requirements under `Project Assistant` tab. Or you can also specify if you want .Net Framework to be installed as part of installation from **Installation Designer (Tab) -> Application Data (Navigation Node in left pane) -> Redistributables**

You can also create custom requirements from **Project Assistant -> Installation Requirements -> Create Custom Software condition**. Select **Registry Entry** from the drop-down to search. In next step, you can provide Registry Root, Registry Key Path and value to look for.

You can also see how to set [Registry Comparison Settings](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/SteConRegComp.htm)

Comment: In the installation requirements the highest check that is available is `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Full Package` so that can't help to add a prerequisite check for .Net framework 4.5.2.

Comment: @RBT Please chek your system if it has .Net 4.5 installed. It should appear. Otherwise, you can create a custom requirement of your own. There you would be guided by a wizard and you can specify search criteria for files, folders, registry values. Check the appropriate registry value and you can check if .NET version is installed on the target system or not.

Comment: I've `.Net Framework 4.6.1` installed on my development box still it doesn't show `.Net Framework 4.5.2` prerequisite option in the installation requirements view. How to go for custom requirement as you are suggesting?

Comment: Navigate to **Installation Requirements**. You will notice **Create a custom software condition** in the left. Click on it and you will be guided through by a wizard. You can find out if .NET is installed using a registry value.

Comment: I can see it now. But it provides an option only to check the presence or absence of a registry key. for checking .net framework we need to check a specific value of the key as told [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#net_d). How can I achieve that?

Comment: @RBT what version of InstallShield you are using. I guess it is not possible in Limited Edition.

Comment: will it be possible for you to add the details of creating the custom software condition in your post? I can try checking if I'm missing something may be.

Comment: @RBT Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

The conditions we have to change as below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear description with screen shot. I make my job easy.